# Net::Telnet::Cisco to router from different source address

Tags: perl, telnet, cisco

I have a server with eth0 and eth1.

```
eth0 = 10.0.0.10
eth1 = 10.10.0.10
```

Now if I do the following, telnet uses the IP address from eth0.

```
    $device_object = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new( Host => $Router);
    $device_object->login( Name => $Username, Passcode => $Password) || die "Can't login to $HOST\n$!\n";
    @output = $session->cmd('show ip int brief');
    print @output;
```

How can I use eth1 as source address to connect to the cisco router, execute the command and get the output?

Answer (score 0):

The module inherits from [IO::Socket::INET](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aINET), read about `LocalAddr`.

Comment: Hi daxim, thanks a lot for your reply. But how can I send a command to the router and get its output?

Comment: Just read the documentation already, that simple use case is explained right there in the [synopsis](http://p3rl.org/Net::Telnet::Cisco#SYNOPSIS).

Comment: Hi daxim, I know the synopsis of Net::Telnet::Cisco but I don't know how to send a command to the router and get its output via IO::Socket::INET. Do you have also a Synopsis link or somethin similar?